# jQuery countdown with moment Js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I was looking into using this combination of jquery countdown plugin with moment js as shown on this [documentation](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/timezone-aware.html).

However, either I am not using the correct versions or something else is broken. Any ideas? Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7312sm3/4/).

```
var nextYear = moment.tz("2019-01-01 00:00", "America/Sao_Paulo");

$('#clock').countdown(nextYear.toDate(), function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't add external resources for **jQuery** library and **countdown** plugin itself.

**UPDATE:**

so the resulting example would be something like next:

```
<div id="clock"></div>

<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var nextYear = moment.tz("2019-01-01 00:00", "America/Sao_Paulo");

        $('#clock').countdown(nextYear.toDate(), function(event) {
            $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are right. Well I think I fixed it now but it still doesnt work.

Comment: @user3628807 please use https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js instead of https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.2/jquery.countdown-uk.js

Comment: I still can't get it to work with my project. The console is throwing error "moment is not defined"

Comment: @user3628807 please review the example from the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
    <div class="timer" id="countdown"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myDate = new Date();

myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2);

$("#countdown").countdown(myDate, function(event) {
  $(this).html(
    event.strftime('<div  ><div  >%D</div><span  >days</span></div><div  ><div  >%H</div><span  >hrs</span></div><div  ><div  >%M</div><span  >mins</span></div><div  ><div  >%S</div><span  >sec</span></div>')
  );
});
    </script>
```